# Access Minikube Services from public IP

Tags: kubernetes, ip, minikube

Currently trying to set up a minikube development environment on a VM which I created on proxmox.

I followed this guide:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/

I can access the services with curl from the server, but I can not access them via the (internal) ip from the VM, for example from another client.

If I check the ip address with "minikube ip" it shows an internal ip address, 192.168.49.2.

How can I get the Services exposed to the physical NIC IP Address?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried #minikube service <your service name>  it will pop up the browser and you can access if u have done that u just find the ip network of the VM you working with and change vm's network to bridge.

Comment: This will heavily depend on the environment you are in and the `minikube --driver`. I'd reckon you could use the `--driver=none` as it would expose all of your workload directly on the `VM NIC` and allow external access (assuming full connectivity from `Proxmox` side). You could also consider creating your Kubernetes solution with other tools.